# Lagrange Multiplier in lm.LMtests (spdep package for R)

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

Are the Lagrange values comparable in lm.LMtests?

If both RLMerr and RLMlag are significant, would the test with the largest Lagrange value be considered 'better' at explaining the spatial relationship for the given model? Or 'better' at explaining which type of spatial autocorrelation is most prevalent in the model?

This is my first question, so apologies for probably not following the necessary protocol/formatting/salutation OR if this belongs in some other silo of StackExchange.

Comment: (+1) For reference, an account of these tests can be found online at http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1538-4632.1988.tb00159.x/pdf (Anselin 1988). A description of `lm.LMtests` appears at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/spdep.pdf.

Comment: Thank you, @whuber! The Anselin paper is just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Anselin in this manual (page 12)](http://labs.bio.unc.edu/Buckley/documents/AnselinIntroSpatRegres.pdf):

the first thing is to assess which of the `LMerr` and `LMlag` have significant `p-values`. If both are significant, then the next step is to compare the`p-values` of the robust forms `RLMerr` and `RLMlag`.